# Access SQL Query - Only extracting value if it is same for the whole group

Tags: sql, ms-access, ms-access-2010

I'm trying to write a query in Access 2010 based on the following simple data set:

```
**Lot   Fruit**
1   Mango
1   Mango
1   Apple
1   Orange
2   Apple
2   Apple
2   Apple
3   Apple
3   Mango
4   Mango
4   Mango
4   Mango
5   Apple
5   Apple
```

I only want to extract those `Lot no.` where fruit has only one type within each `Lot`.

For example, say I want to get data where `Fruit = "Apple"`, then it should only pull data where Lot has only "Apple" no other fruit in the same Lot.

In our example if I want all lot which have only Apple, then query should bring the following result.

```
Lot Fruit
2   Apple
2   Apple
2   Apple
5   Apple
5   Apple
```

I have tried various SQL queries but with no luck, any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT Lot
FROM mytable
GROUP BY Lot
HAVING COUNT(CASE WHEN Fruit <> 'Apple' THEN 1 END) = 0
```

Alternatively try:

```
SELECT DISTINCT Lot
FROM mytable AS t1    
WHERE Fruit = 'Apple' AND 
      NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1
                  FROM mytable AS t2
                  WHERE t1.Lot = t2.Lot AND t2.Fruit <> 'Apple')
```

It's also possible to use `LEFT JOIN`:

```
SELECT DISTINCT Lot
FROM mytable AS t1
LEFT JOIN mytable AS t2 ON t1.Lot = t2.Lot AND t2.Fruit <> 'Apple'
WHERE t1.Fruit = 'Apple' AND t2.Lot IS NULL
```

Comment: Thank you for reply. Unfortunately Access 2010 SQL doesn't like the syntax and showed error message: Syntax error (missing operator) in query express 'COUNT(CASE WHEN Fruit <> "Apple" TRHEN 1 end)= 0'

Comment: @Alchy That's a pitty. It's just ANSI SQL! :=(

Comment: Great!, second query worked without any problem, thank you Giorgos, :)